# Is it possible to find the shift values in x and y coordinates of a dataset in machine learning of python?

Tags: graph, python

I am trying to find the shift or scroll values of a dataset in x and y coordinates, which is overlaid over another dataset. The unprocessed state of the data is shown in the figure labeled "Before". Here, dots are the obervational dataset and line is the model dataset. I want the model dataset to fit observational dataset as shown in the figure labeled as "After". This fitting was done manually by given these values directly. My Before/After image can be seen after python code executed.

I have no idea how can we find the shift values in x and y coordinates of the model dataset. My datasets are in the minimal working code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

model = np.array([(0.310, -0.687), (0.407, -0.355), (0.455, -0.142), (0.504, 0.061), (0.552, 0.238), 
                  (0.601,  0.380), (0.698,  0.549), (0.746,  0.581), (0.795, 0.587), (0.859, 0.567), 
                  (0.956,  0.511), (1.053,  0.473), (1.150,  0.489), (1.199, 0.523), (1.296, 0.640), 
                  (1.393,  0.812), (1.490,  0.981), (1.587,  1.189), (1.684, 1.386), (1.781, 1.572), 
                  (1.878, 1.766)])

obser = np.array([(0.212, -0.114), (0.199, 0.017), (0.259, 0.020), (0.199, 0.076), (0.297, 0.082), 
                  (0.735, 0.085), (0.641, 0.104), (0.791, 0.104), (0.681, 0.109), (0.606, 0.132), 
                  (0.262, 0.135), (0.813, 0.137), (0.334, 0.157), (0.565, 0.165), (0.647, 0.170), 
                  (0.876, 0.174), (0.746, 0.186), (0.509, 0.197), (0.398, 0.203), (0.693, 0.207), 
                  (0.829, 0.215), (0.299, 0.226), (0.585, 0.228), (0.549, 0.242), (0.430, 0.242), 
                  (0.637, 0.253), (0.511, 0.257), (0.918, 0.268), (0.813, 0.269), (0.746, 0.271), 
                  (0.336, 0.288), (0.449, 0.297), (0.398, 0.299), (0.783, 0.306), (0.578, 0.312), 
                  (0.871, 0.330), (0.515, 0.345), (0.468, 0.353), (0.818, 0.380), (0.936, 0.391), 
                  (0.889, 0.416), (0.876, 0.503), (1.027, 0.522), (1.040, 0.601), (0.965, 0.656), 
                  (1.130, 0.796), (1.224, 0.845), (1.261, 0.964), (1.378, 1.149)])

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(9,6))
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5, hspace=0)

# how can we obtain the shift values of [0.37, 0.32] with machine learning?
model2 = model - [0.37, 0.32]

ax1.invert_yaxis()
ax1.set_xlabel("BmV")
ax1.set_ylabel("UmB")
ax1.scatter(obser[:, 0], obser[:, 1], s=2, c="black")
ax1.plot(model[:, 0], model[:, 1], linewidth=1, c="red")
ax1.text(0.7, 0.96, 'Before', verticalalignment='top', horizontalalignment='left', 
transform = ax1.transAxes, color = 'black', fontsize=12)

ax2.invert_yaxis()
ax2.set_xlabel("BmV")
ax2.set_ylabel("UmB")
ax2.scatter(obser[:, 0], obser[:, 1], s=2, c="black")
ax2.plot(model2[:, 0], model2[:, 1], linewidth=1, c="red")
ax2.text(0.8, 0.96, 'After', verticalalignment='top', horizontalalignment='left', 
transform = ax2.transAxes, color = 'black', fontsize=12)

plt.show()
```

I think that this scrolling can be done with machine learning in python. But I don't know exactly how. Can anybody help me?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "fit".  If you want them to have the same mean, median, or center of mass using some other weighting, that wouldn't be hard because those all shift with the data.  If you want to minimize the area of the symmetric difference of the convex hulls, that would be more difficult.

Comment: it is possible to calculate the differences between model and observed values and sum of these differences must minimum as much possible. My main problem is how we can perform this. Initially, the first sum of differences are calculated easly, but at second step, my problem is to decide how much shift should be made on which axis and direction (ın or out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr: Make the averages line up.

You commented that you want to minimize the sum of the differences between the model and observed values.  Mathematically, this can be written ∑<sub>ij</sub>|m<sub>i</sub>-o<sub>j</sub>-s|, where s is the shift.  As with the standard deviation / mean deviation (see [stats.se](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/118) or [mo](https://mathoverflow.net/q/1048)), it turns out to be better to instead minimize ∑<sub>ij</sub>(m<sub>i</sub>-o<sub>j</sub>-s)<sup>2</sup>.

Differentiating, this is minimized when 0=-2∑<sub>ij</sub>(m<sub>i</sub>-o<sub>j</sub>-s).  If we say that there are M model points and O observation points, then this means 0=-2(∑<sub>i</sub>m<sub>i</sub>)O+2(∑<sub>j</sub>o<sub>j</sub>)M+2sOM.  Therefore, s=(∑<sub>i</sub>m<sub>i</sub>)/M-(∑<sub>j</sub>o<sub>j</sub>)/O, the difference of their averages.  (A detail person might notice we were working with one dimension; which works out because the square distance can decompose into the square distance along each axis aka the Pythagorean Theorem.)

Coming back to your data, this would mean that you would want
`model3 = model - (model.mean(axis=0) - obser.mean(axis=0))`
which is shifting by `[0.35096599,0.27984354]`.  Although to be honest, I don't see much of a difference between model2 and model3.

Comment: You are really great, Teepeemm, this solution is awesome. I will test this with other datasets that are need to be solved. Thank you very much for your kind attention.

Comment: As a followup thought, another "fit" would be "minimize the difference of the observations to the function defined by the model".  That would be much more complicated, starting with how would you figure out the function defined by the model.

Comment: I made some adjustment in my python code to improve a better approximation 
as bmv = model[:,0] and umb = model[:,1], I defined a function as
f = interpolate.interp1d(bmv, umb, kind='cubic', bounds_error=False) by interpolate of scipy. But I could not go as far as I expected. Is it possible to do this like that.

Comment: The standard least squares approach with that f would be to minimize ∑<sub>i</sub>( f(o<sub>i,x</sub>-s<sub>x</sub>)-o<sub>i,y</sub>-s<sub>y</sub> )<sup>2</sup>.  Without an explicit formula for f (and possibly even with), that would probably require a numerical analysis approach.

Comment: An explicit formula for model is not possible to form. Thanks anyway for everything.